# Prove that a certain function is upper semicontinuous

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

The following definition can be found [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=wdTntZ_N0tYC&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=complex%20semicontinuous%20function&source=bl&ots=GoEQeLmVk6&sig=mbM7OzOORZax54_T6ZjaNDtcqTI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhtuqi-77PAhXnL8AKHXC8AZIQ6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=complex%20semicontinuous%20function&f=false).

> **Definition.** Let $X$ be a topological space. A function $f: X \to [-\infty,\infty)$ is said to be *upper semicontinuous* if for every $x_0 \in X$ and $M > f(x_0)$ a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ exists such that $M > f(x)$ holds for every $x \in U$.

Consider $X = \Omega$, where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Assume $F: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous on $\Omega$. Then $\log |F|$ is upper semicontinuous on $\Omega$. How do I prove this? I think we can distinguish two cases: either $F(x_0) = 0$ or $F(x_0) \neq 0$. In both cases we can find such neighbourhoods by the continuity of $F$.

Comment: Do you really mean $[-\infty$,$\infty$)?

Comment: @mathlover Yes. Added reference.

Comment: Right, distinguish between $F(x_0) = 0$ and $F(x_0) \neq 0$, use the continuity of $F$, and the monotonicity of $\log$ to prove the assertion.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am somehow stucked in proving this rigorously, I tried to use the defition of continuity involving relative neighbourhoods in which $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ holds. Somehow it confuses me.

Comment: Okay. First, can you show that a real-valued function is upper semicontinuous at all points where it is continuous? That would deal with the $F(x_0) \neq 0$ case, since $\log \lvert F\rvert$ is a continuous real-valued function on $\Omega \setminus F^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm...I try. Assume $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $M > f(x_0)$. Then we have for any $\varepsilon$ that $-\varepsilon < f(x) - f(x_0) < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x - x_0| < \delta$. That is the point where I am not sure how to proceed. I think one has to distinguish between negative an positive $M$.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether $M$ is positive or negative. How do you need to choose $\varepsilon$ to make sure that $f(x) < M$ whenever $\lvert f(x) - f(x_0)\rvert < \varepsilon$?

Comment: @DanielFischer One has to choose $\varepsilon = M - f(x_0)$. How do I proceed in the other case?

Comment: For $F(x_0) = 0$, we have $\log \lvert F(x_0)\rvert = -\infty$. So we can't use $M - f(x_0)$ there. But we want $\log \lvert F(x)\rvert < M$. Can you rewrite that as an inequality for $\lvert F(x)\rvert$?

Comment: @DanielFischer You mean $|F(x)| < e^M$?

Comment: Exactly. So if $F(x_0) = 0$, can you find a neighbourhood of $x_0$ on which we have $\lvert F(x) \rvert < e^M$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes. This is due to the continuity of $F$ at $0$ right?

Comment: Right. Can you gather the pieces together to write an answer to your question?

Comment: Yes I can. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Don't forget to add an answer to your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0 \in \Omega$ such that $F(x_0) \neq 0$ and $M > \log|F(x_0)|$. Then $M - \log|F(x_0)| > 0$ and by the continuity of $\log|F|$ (as a composition of continuous functions) we find a neighbourhood $U$ around $x_0$ such that $$|\log|F(x)| - \log|F(x_0)|| < M - \log|F(x_0)|$$ or equivalently $$\log|F(x)|< M$$

Let $x_0 \in \Omega$ such that $F(x_0) = 0$. Then $\log|F(x_0)| = -\infty$. Further $M > \log|F(x)|$ implies $|F(x)| < e^M$ or equivalently $$|F(x) - F(x_0)| < e^M$$ But $F$ is continuous at $x_0$, so we can find a neighbourhood $V$ around $x_0$ such that above inequality is fulfilled.

Many thanks goes to Daniel Fischer!